# Can map::find and iterator::second be used in one condition

Tags: c++11, stl, iterator

I have such a piece of code:

```
std::map<int, int> mp;
// do something
auto itor = mp.find(some_value);
if (itor != mp.end() && itor->second == some_other_value) {
    // do something
}
```

I'm worrying about which expression would be evaluated first, `itor != mp.end()` or `itor->second == some_other_value`?

If the second one is evaluated firstly (because of some compiler-optimization maybe?), it might get an undefined behavior because `itor == mp.end()` may be true.

Should I worry about this issue so that I have to code like this:

```
if (itor != mp.end) {
    if (itor->second == some_other_value) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No worries; your code is fine.

If the first condition of `if (a && b)` is false, then the second condition is not evaluated.

Look up "short-circuit evaluation"

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) has some info.

Answer (score 0):

Logical And - && - expression is evaluated **left to right** so `itor != mp.end()` will be evaluated initially. Moreover, it returns true only if both expressions return true, hence if the first one is false the second one is not checked.

so the first case should work.